# Cannot update ES settings using ElasticSearch-PHP

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-php

There is already an index in ES. I am using  ElasticSearch-PHP as client.
According to [ES docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/5.0/_index_management_operations.html)  these code  should change ES settings:

```
$params = [
   'index' => 'my_index',
   'body' => [
      'settings' => [
         'number_of_replicas' => 0,
         'refresh_interval' => -1
       ]
    ]
];

$response = $client->indices()->putSettings($params);
```

But after running code this error is shown:

```
**Fatal error** : Uncaught exception 'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\Forbidden403Exception' with message '{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"}],"type":"cluster_block_exception","reason":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"},"status":403}
```

How can I solve it?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your elasticsearch server host machine is probably low on storage.
Run the following in Kibana Dev tools. Should at least temporarily fix the issue.

```
PUT .kibana/_settings
{
  "index": {
    "blocks": {
      "read_only_allow_delete": "false"
    }
  }
}
```